# Multi-Column Photo Gallery

Tags: php, css, multiple-columns, image-gallery

I have a php powered photo gallery that should display pictures in a three-column layout. Each picture will have the same width (i.e., the column width), but since the aspect ratio varies, so does its height. The pictures are in a semi-random order, so the displaying order (filling rows or columns) does not matter.

I tried to set this up as a css multicolumn layout:

```
#gallerycontainer {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 8px;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 8px;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 8px;
}
```

When everything is loaded, this matches what I want to achive. The problem is the loading phase: With one image after the other being loaded and hence changed to their correct height, the total height of the `#gallerycontainer` content changes after every image load and therefore the images get redistributed between the columns a lot, producing an annoying visual effect. I think I would be able to get rid of this by setting the specific height and width of the `img`s when generating the page in PHP. However, I do not know what their display width will be (the width of `#gallerycontainer` and hence of the columns depends on the width of the browser window), so I cannot set these values explicitly.

Is there any CSS trick to have every picture in the right column even before it is loaded?

*Notes*: I want this to work with as little Javascript as possible and especially without external frameworks or suites, so Masonry is not an option here. Also, I have a working "cheating" solution (see below), I am mainly looking for better ways to solve this and at the same time documenting my solution in case anyone else has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

My first approach to solve this was to introduce column-breaks explicitly by my PHP code to maintain the CSS multi-column setup. So I would determine the position of these in PHP and add the following CSS:

```
.img {
  -webkit-column-break-after: avoid;
  break-after: avoid;
.columnbreak {
  -webkit-column-break-after: always;
  break-after: column;
}
```

However, browser support for avoiding pagebreaks is very bad so far. I actually sometimes ended up getting a fourth column in my three-column layout when the manual column breaks did not coincide with Chrome's automatic column breaks, ignoring the `avoid`.

---

I ended up using three CSS-positioned `div`s for my three columns and having PHP put them in these three columns explicitly. This gives me the visual result that I want, but it feels like an unsatisfying "cheating" solution.

Here is my CSS for these columns:

```
.column {
  position:absolute;
  width:32.5%;
  width:calc((100% - 16px)/3);
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
.column:nth-child(2) {
  left:33.75%;
  left:calc((100% - 16px)/3 + 8px);
}
.column:nth-child(3) {
  left:67.5%;
  left:calc((100% - 16px)*2/3 + 16px);
}
```

In case anyone wants to use my solution for their project, here is also my PHP code:

```
$totalheight=0;
while($pic=readdir($dir))
{
  if(strtolower(substr($pic,-3))=="jpg")
  {
    $pics[]=$pic;
    $size=getimagesize('galerie/'.$galerie.'/'.$pic);
    $totalheight+=$size[1]/$size[0];
  }
}
$columnheight=0;
$columnbreaks=0;
$piccontent.= "<div class='column'>";
foreach ( $pics as $pic )
{
  $size=getimagesize('galerie/'.$galerie.'/'.$pic);
  if($columnheight+$size[1]/$size[0]/2 >= $totalheight/3 && $columnbreaks<2) {
    $piccontent.= "</div><div class='column'>"; //start a new column
    $columnheight=0;
    $columnbreaks++;
  }
  $columnheight+=$size[1]/$size[0];

  $piccontent.='<div class="img"><img src="photos_tn/'.$galerie.'/'.$pic.'" alt=""></div>';  
}
$piccontent.= "</div>";
```